# Reading the contents of all files in current directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can print out names of all files in my current directory using the following python script:

```
import psycopg2
from config import config
import os

path = 'path_to_current_dir'
params = config()

conn = None
try:
    #read the connection parameters
    params = config()
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.plt'):
                print(file)
                #f = open(file, 'r')

    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Output:

```
20090205094627.plt
20090312135415.plt
20090216055722.plt
20090311065333.plt
20090418032222.plt
20090119072534.plt
```

I want to read the content of each file, So I uncomment the `open(..)` statement in the script above. However, even the first file in the directory is not read, reporting the following error:

```
$ python check.py 
20090205094627.plt
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20090205094627.plt'
```

I am missing the right logic to read these files. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you forget to prepend the subdirectory name to the file? You are only printing the filename, not the full (relative) path of the file. You'll need at least `path`.

Comment: You need to combine the directory name with the filename. The files are not in the directory from which you run the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the full path to the open function

```
f = open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r')
```

It will be better practice to open the file with `with`

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as f:
    f.read()
```

with `with` the file will close after exiting the with statement this way you will be sure that the file closes after you use it.

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Comment: Sure, now I can carry on.